# How can I view the techniques (unlocked and yet-to-be-unlocked) in Hitman: Absolution (on the PC)?

Tags: hitman-absolution

I'm playing Absolution, and I get a notification when I unlock a new technique. However, I can't figure out what the technique does unless I look it up online, and I can't find a list of all the techniques I've unlocked already. When I hit F1 to view my score, I can see the next technique that I'm working towards, but again no description and no full list. Is there any way in game to view at least a list of the unlocked techniques and their descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of each mission, if you've unlocked any new techniques during said mission it will list them in a pop-up and tell you what they do before you see your score for the mission.  However, past that there is no interface that lists all of them as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

http://m.ign.com/wikis/hitman-absolution/Assassin_Techniques
This is a lost of the techniques, and if you don't know how to unlock them it is simple just get a relatively high score on each mission and you will unlock a technique, preferably silent assassin but I think any high rating works.